# How to create ALTER READ ONLY using PL/SQL for multiple tables?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, alter

I'd like to know how to use `PL/SQL` to `ALTER` tables to `READ ONLY` through creating a `PROCEDURE`. I tried the below code block so far :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_PROJ_REQU_READ_ONLY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE projects READ ONLY;
  ALTER TABLE request_activities READ ONLY;
  ALTER TABLE proj_rec_services READ ONLY;           
END UPDATE_PROJ_REQU_READ_ONLY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `ALTER` all the tables in the current schema, then create this procedure as

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_PR_READ_ONLY IS
  v_sql VARCHAR2(150);
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
           (
            SELECT *
              FROM user_objects o
             WHERE o.object_type  
           )
  LOOP
    v_sql := 'ALTER TABLE '||c.object_name||' READ ONLY';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
  END LOOP;          
END;
/
```

**or**  If you want to `ALTER` only three individual tables, then create this procedure as

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_PR_READ_ONLY IS
  v_sql VARCHAR2(150);
  v_tab owa.vc_arr;
BEGIN
  v_tab(1):='PROJECTS'; v_tab(2):='REQUEST_ACTIVITIES'; v_tab(3):='PROJ_REC_SERVICES';
  FOR i in 1..3
  LOOP
    v_sql := 'ALTER TABLE '||v_tab(i)||' READ ONLY';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
  END LOOP;              
END;
/
```

by looping through array values set to those table's name.

Whatever procedure create, call as

```
SQL> EXEC UPDATE_PR_READ_ONLY;
```

*Note that*

- adding procedure name after the last `END` of the `PROCEDURE` is
  optional, and if added it should be the same as the `PROCEDURE` name.
  Thus, `UPDATE_PROJ_REQU_READ_ONLY` should be converted to
  `UPDATE_PR_READ_ONLY` in this case.
- expression `FOR EACH ROW` is used for database triggers, but not for
  stored procedures
- add a keyword `IS` or `AS` after procedure name in the first line,
  more preferable to use `OR REPLACE` option after `CREATE` keyword
- a `DDL` statement cannot be issued without using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`
  within a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table_name READ ONLY;

Comment: so what you want

Comment: I found the answer. Your answer is not what I was looking. If you can, you can delete it.

Comment: can you please share your solution for my understanding.